# Ambiguous overload between int32_t or int64_t parameters when passing long

Tags: c++, gcc, overload-resolution

**Note:** This is very similar to [Determine number of bits in integral type at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578359/determine-number-of-bits-in-integral-type-at-compile-time), however this is a much simplified version, all contained in a single `.cpp`

The problem is with functions like

```
 msg(int32_t);
 msg(int64_t);
```

a call like

```
long long myLong = 6;
msg(myLong);    // Won't compile on gcc (4.6.3), call is ambiguous
```

This compiles on MSVC. Can anyone provide an explanation of why this fails on gcc (I'm assuming it's probably to do with the fact gcc is usually strictly standards compliant) and an example of how to correctly achieve the same effect?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <boost/integer.hpp>

using namespace std;

void msg(int v) { cout << "int: " << sizeof(int) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg(long v) { cout << "long: " << sizeof(long) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg(long long v) { cout << "long long: " << sizeof(long long) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }

void msg2(int32_t v) { cout << "int32_t: " << sizeof(int32_t) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg2(int64_t v) { cout << "int64_t: " << sizeof(int64_t) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg2(uint32_t v) { cout << "uint32_t: " << sizeof(uint32_t) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg2(uint64_t v) { cout << "uint64_t: " << sizeof(uint64_t) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }


int main()
{
 
    int myInt = -5;
    long myLong = -6L;
    long long myLongLong = -7LL;

    unsigned int myUInt = 5;
    unsigned int myULong = 6L;
    unsigned long long myULongLong = 7LL;

    msg(myInt);
    msg(myLong);
    msg(myLongLong);

    msg2(myInt);
    msg2(myLong);     // fails on gcc 4.6.3 (32 bit)
    msg2(myLongLong);
  
    msg2(myUInt);
    msg2(myULong);   // fails on gcc 4.6.3 (32 bit)
    msg2(myULongLong);

   return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// Output from MSVC  (and gcc if you omit lines that would be commented out)
int: 4 5
long: 4 6
long long: 8 7
int32_t: 4 -5
int32_t: 4 -6   // omitted on gcc
int64_t: 8 -7
uint32_t: 4 5
uint32_t: 4 6   // omitted on gcc
uint64_t: 8 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greg hits the nail on the head: `int32_t` and `int64_t` are typedefs which may or may not be `long`. If neither is a typedef for `long`, overload resolution can fail. Both `long->int32_t` and `long->int64_t` have Rank=Promotion (Table 12, 13.3.3.1.2)

Answer (score 4):

Whether the code will compile or not is implementation defined.  There is no type `int32_t` nor `int64_t`; these are simply typedef's to an existing integral type.  If the type happens to be one that is already overloaded (`int`, `long` or `long long`), which is almost certainly the case, then you have multiple definitions of the same function.  If they are in the same translation unit, it is a compile time error, requiring a diagnostic.  If they are in different translation units, it's undefined behavior, but I imagine that most implementations will also generate an error.

In your case, the best solution is probably to make `msg` a template, and pass the name of the type in as an argument.

Comment: How can it be the case that `int32_t` and `int64_t` are the same type? Shouldn't one have twice the bits of the other (as shown in the output of the test code)? At any rate, gcc has `typedef int int32_t` and `typedef long long int int64_t`, so they are not the same in this particular case, even if they could be the same on some other architecture.

Comment: There are no multiple definitions of the same functions. This could happen only if `int32_t` is the same as `int64_t` - which is impossible.
The actual problem here is that in gcc on 32bit platforms, neither `int32_t` nor `int64_t` is typedef of `long` (first is just `int`, second one is `long long`). This is why, when you try to call msg(long) it is ambiguous

Comment: @Greg Yes.  I'd missed the fact that the functions had different names, which of course changes everything.  (Or not, because as you point out, the exact type of `int32_t` and `int64_t` is implementation defined.  And since there are three calls to `msg2`, with three different types, at least one will fail to be an exact match, and depending on the actual typedefs, may be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

| Disclaimer |
| --- |
| This solution was originally posted by the author within their question. |

The solution is provide a function that successfully maps `int`, `long` and `long long` to the appropriate `int32_t` or `int64_t`. This can be done trivially at run time via `if (sizeof(int)==sizeof(int32_t))` type statements, but a compile-time solution is preferable. A compile-time solution is available via the use of [`boost::enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).

The following works on MSVC10 and gcc 4.6.3.
The solution could be further enhanced by disabling for non-integral types, but that is outside the scope of this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <boost/integer.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_signed.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_unsigned.hpp>

using namespace std;

template <class InputT>
typename boost::enable_if_c<sizeof(InputT)==sizeof(int32_t) && boost::is_signed<InputT>::value,
 int32_t>::type ConvertIntegral(InputT z) { return static_cast<int32_t>(z); }

template <class InputT>
typename boost::enable_if_c<sizeof(InputT)==sizeof(int64_t) && boost::is_signed<InputT>::value, 
int64_t>::type ConvertIntegral(InputT z) { return static_cast<int64_t>(z); }

template <class InputT>
typename boost::enable_if_c<sizeof(InputT)==sizeof(uint32_t) && boost::is_unsigned<InputT>::value, 
uint32_t>::type ConvertIntegral(InputT z) { return static_cast<uint32_t>(z); }

template <class InputT>
typename boost::enable_if_c<sizeof(InputT)==sizeof(uint64_t) && boost::is_unsigned<InputT>::value, 
uint64_t>::type ConvertIntegral(InputT z) { return static_cast<uint64_t>(z); }

void msg(int v) { cout << "int: " << sizeof(int) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg(long v) { cout << "long: " << sizeof(long) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg(long long v) { cout << "long long: " << sizeof(long long) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }


void msg2(int32_t v) { cout << "int32_t: " << sizeof(int32_t) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg2(int64_t v) { cout << "int64_t: " << sizeof(int64_t) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg2(uint32_t v) { cout << "uint32_t: " << sizeof(uint32_t) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }
void msg2(uint64_t v) { cout << "uint64_t: " << sizeof(uint64_t) << ' ' << v << '\n'; }

int main()
{
 
    int myInt = -5;
    long myLong = -6L;
    long long myLongLong = -7LL;

    unsigned int myUInt = 5;
    unsigned int myULong = 6L;
    unsigned long long myULongLong = 7LL;

    msg(myInt);
    msg(myLong);
    msg(myLongLong);

    msg2(ConvertIntegral(myInt));
    msg2(ConvertIntegral(myLong));
    msg2(ConvertIntegral(myLongLong));
  
    msg2(ConvertIntegral(myUInt));
    msg2(ConvertIntegral(myULong));
    msg2(ConvertIntegral(myULongLong));

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, template argument deduction can help in this case, but it's not enough to disambiguate between all the possible typedefs defined in [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>
#include <string_view>
#include <format>

template< std::integral I >
constexpr auto name_of(I v)
    -> std::string_view
{
    if constexpr ( std::same_as<I, char> )
        return "char";
    else if constexpr ( std::unsigned_integral<I> )
        if constexpr ( sizeof v < 2 )
            return "uint8_t";
        else if constexpr ( sizeof v < 4 )
            return "uint16_t";
        else if constexpr ( sizeof v < 8 )
            return "uint32_t";
        else
            return "uint64_t";  
    else
        if constexpr ( sizeof v < 2 )
            return "int8_t";
        else if constexpr ( sizeof v < 4 )
            return "int16_t";
        else if constexpr ( sizeof v < 8 )
            return "int32_t";
        else
            return "int64_t";  
}

template< std::integral I >
void msg2(I v)
{
    std::cout << std::format("{:8}{:3}  ", name_of(v), sizeof v);
    
    if constexpr ( std::same_as<I, char> )
        std::cout << '\'' << v << "\'\n";
    else if constexpr ( sizeof(I) == 1 )
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(v) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << v << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    msg2(-5);
    msg2(-6LL);
    msg2(-7LL);
    msg2(5U);
    msg2(6UL);
    msg2(7ULL);
  
    msg2(int8_t{42});
    msg2((signed char)'a');   // <-- Indistinguishable from int8_t
    msg2('b');
    msg2((unsigned char)'c'); // <-- Same as uint8_t
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qG1zq1Wor)