# Why is this integer implicit conversion ambiguous?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have the following simple example code, of class constructors for two integer types:

```
struct Y
{
  Y(int) {}
  Y(long long) {}
};
```

This is called from:

```
void foo()
{
  char          _char;
  short         _short;
  int           _int;
  long          _long;
  long long     _longlong;

  Y y0 = _char;
  Y y1 = _short;
  Y y2 = _int;
  Y y3 = _long;
  Y y4 = _longlong;
}
```

When I compile this with gcc 4.8.4, in 64 bit mode, I get only a single error:

```
error: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘Y’ is ambiguous
   Y y3 = _long;
          ^
```

What I don't understand is why the `_char` and `_short` conversions are allowed, but the `_long` is ambiguous.

Comment: On your system is `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`  ?

Comment: The short answer is because overload resolution rules are too simple to catch this. It only knows conversions of smaller types -> int, called promotions. And then as a second category every other integer conversion which will be ambiguous against each other,

Comment: The same issue as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10579544/2564301)?

Comment: sizeof(int)=4 , sizeof(long)=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ranks for types of conversions when determining the best viable candidate: Exact Match, Promotion (including integral promotion), and Conversion (including integral conversion).

Any of the integral types smaller than `int` can be *promoted* to `int`, everything else is a conversion. So for `char` and `short`, the promotion is the best viable candidate. For `int` and `long long`, we simply pick the exact match.

For `long`, however, we have two options both of which involve an integral *conversion*. There is no rule to differentiate which of the two conversions is "better", so we end up with an ambiguity. You will have to cast the `long` yourself to the desired type.